# Symfony 4.4 Translation interface problem

Tags: symfony, interface, translation

Recently upgraded app from Symfony 4.3 to 4.4 and in production I have problem with Symfony Translator interface

config:

```
framework:
default_locale: pl
translator:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) in ./vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php on line 24
Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator::trans($id, array $parameters = Array, $domain = NULL, $locale = NULL) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface::trans(string $id, array $parameters = Array, ?string $domain = NULL, ?string $locale = NULL) in ./vendor/symfony/translation/Translator.php on line 32
```

Comment: you probably should use the same versions for symfony/translation and symfony/contracts ;o)

Comment: The problem is that Symfony 4.4 adds typehints and the Translator component isn't compatible with that (yet). I've tried changing some dependency versions but without any success. Probably we will have to wait for the Translator dependency to adopt typehints too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that downgrading to `symfony:translation-contracts:1.1.6` worked for me.
Composer automatically installed the `2.0.0` version of this package, that makes use of typehinting.
The `1.1.6` version does not and makes the `Translator` class compatible again.
It does not use typehinting.

In my `composer.json` file, I fixed the version to `1.1.6`:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.3",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.4",
        "symfony/translation-contracts": "1.1.6"
}
```

P.S. There are more dependencies but I omitted them for readability